# $rootScope.$broadcast usage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-rootscope

I am working with an app where I have the following line at the end of a service in service.js.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('rootScope:Object')
```

Here Object is the output of an API service. If I now want to use this Object in my actual app.js file, how could I use it? What does the above line specify and how to use it in later pages?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

From the given answers tried the following:

In service page:

```
this.getobject=function(){
//http api Function call with result as  response.data = resp 
$rootScope.$broadcast('rootScope:resp',resp);
}
```

In the child scope page:

```
resp=[];
$rootScope.$on('rootScope:resp',function(resp) {
          $scope.resp=resp;
          console.log(resp);

      });
$scope.$on('rootScope:resp', function(e, params){
             console.log(params); // respobject
        });
```

Unfortunately both didn't print anything on console. Any issue with the approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line means that the $rootScope (the highest scope level) will broadcast an event named 'rootScope:Object' to all the children (your app's scopes).

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope, you can add parameters to the `$broadcast()` function to, in your case, pass your Object.
You will have:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('rootScope:Object', myObject)
```

In your child scope, you can easily retrieve this with:

```
$scope.$on('rootScope:Object', function(e, params){
     console.log(params); // myObject
});
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENvjVY) showing loading and displaying data from an API using $broadcast/$on

Comment: As I said here "myObject" is an array returned froma  api response, can I use it in my child scope and assign it to someother array there?

Comment: Yes, you can. I've made a little codepen with a simple api call and response display based on $broadcast/$on : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENvjVY

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question but [broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) does nothing more than dispatch an event downwards to all child scopes.

So, in your service you probably want to have something like:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEventNameHere', actualJavascriptObjectHere);
```

And on the place that you want to listen to this event, you will have something like this:

```
 $scope.$on('myEventNameHere', function(actualJavascriptObjectHere) { 
      console.log(actualJavascriptObjectHere); 
 });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's actually more likely that you'll have `$scope.$on..` instead of `$rootScope.$on...`. Also, your object will be the second parameter of your callback, the first one is an event object